# Add null elements to jsoup document

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to parse data from a webpage which can be provided the following:

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Rent</div>
    <div class="Ort">TestCity 3., Roads Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 950 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 72 m²</div>
    <div class="Zimmer"><span class='Label'>Zimmer:</span> 3</div>
</div>
```

However, sometimes these structure looks totally different like:

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Rent</div>
    <div class="Ort">Test 3., Road Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 919 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 84 m²</div>
    <div class="Zimmer"><span class='Label'>Zimmer:</span> 3</div>
    <div class="EigTitel">weitere Eigenschaften:</div>
    <div class='EigListe'>Shower, Balcony, Dog</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Sale</div>
    <div class="Ort">Test 4., Road Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 919 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 84 m²</div>
</div>
```

How to parse this in Jsoup so that when the fields which are missing, are getting a null value and my data stays consistent.

At the moment I am parsing the data like that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Elements title = doc.select("div[class=Title]");
Elements art = doc.select("div[class=Art]");
Elements location = doc.select("div[class=Ort]");
Elements price = doc.select("div[class=Preis]");
Elements size = doc.select("div[class=Groesse]");
Elements numberOfRooms = doc.select("div[class=Zimmer]");
Elements furtherProperties = doc.select("div[class=EigListe]");
```

titleList = new ArrayList();
            artList = new ArrayList();
            locationList = new ArrayList();
            priceList = new ArrayList();
            sizeList = new ArrayList();
            numberOfRoomsList = new ArrayList();
            furtherPropertiesList = new ArrayList();

```
        //price
        for (Element element : price) {
            priceList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
        //size
        for (Element element : size) {
            sizeList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
        //numberOfRooms
        for (Element element : numberOfRooms) {
            numberOfRoomsList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
        //furtherProperties
        for (Element element : furtherProperties) {
            furtherPropertiesList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
        //location
        for (Element element : location) {
            locationList.add(element.text().toString());
        }   
        //art
        for (Element element : art) {
            artList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
        //title
        for (Element element : title) {
            titleList.add(element.text().toString());
        }

        log.info(ListstoString());

        //add everything to the main domain List
        for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size(); i++) {
            Property prop = new Property();
            //price
            prop.setPrice(priceList.get(i));
            //size
            prop.setSize(sizeList.get(i));
            //number of rooms
            prop.setNumberOfRooms(numberOfRoomsList.get(i));
            //furtherProperties
            prop.setFurtherProperties(furtherPropertiesList.get(i));
            //location
            prop.setLocation(locationList.get(i));
            //art
            prop.setTransactionType(artList.get(i));
            //title
            prop.setTitle(titleList.get(i));
            //set date
            prop.setCrawlingDate(new Date());
            list.add(prop);
        }
```

Any recommendation how to accomplish that?

Comment: As you say the DTD can change, check each element line by line and extract those class fields and accordingly process the defined values alone. This way you keep your program dynamic. Your sample code is static and will not generalize well.

Comment: @mario23 What do you exactly mean by `check each element line by line and extract those class fields and accordingly process the defined values alone.`. My problem is, that if I select the document via jsoup it only takes the available elements. Therefore, isn`t it possible to parse the class `class="InseratDaten"`, like that so that I can add null to the missing `class` elements? If yes, how can I implement that?

Comment: Okay this seems simple. I'll add an algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you select the available elements, Use `for` loop instead of `foreach` and "check" whether each element is `!null` before adding the element to the `arrayList`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);  
Elements title = doc.select("div[class=Title]");  
Elements art = doc.select("div[class=Art]");  
Elements location = doc.select("div[class=Ort]");  
Elements price = doc.select("div[class=Preis]");  
Elements size = doc.select("div[class=Groesse]");  
Elements numberOfRooms = doc.select("div[class=Zimmer]");  
Elements furtherProperties = doc.select("div[class=EigListe]");  

//for price  
  Int i;  
  for (i=0; i < element.length; i++) {  
        if(element[i] != null){  
          priceList.add(element.text().toString());  
        }else{
          priceList.add("null/undef/whatever");
        }
  }
```

//similarly for other classes as well

//for further processing, check each element in the list for other than 'null/undef/whatever'